# Method Swizzling does not work when methods have parameters

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I have been doing method swizzling (Objective-C to Swift) for my unit tests and they're perfectly working, except when the time came I need to swizzle methods with parameters.

Old method to be swizzled:

```
@interface FNServerApiRequests : NSObject
+ (void) pullTypesFromServer:(void (^)(id responseJson))completionBlock error:(MKNKErrorBlock)errorBlock;
@end
```

Then my new Swift function:

```
extension FNServerApiRequests {
  @objc
  class func swizzledPullTypes(fromServer completionBlock: @escaping (Any) -> Void, error errorBlock: @escaping MKNKErrorBlock) {
    print("swizzledPullTypes")
    let dic = FNTestUtils.getJsonDictionaryFile("pull-types.json")
    completionBlock(dic!)
  }
}
```

Then finally:

```
  func setupSwizzling() {
    let originalMethod = class_getClassMethod(FNServerApiRequests.self, #selector(FNServerApiRequests.pullTypes(fromServer:error:)))
    let swizzledMethod = class_getClassMethod(FNServerApiRequests.self, #selector(FNServerApiRequests.swizzledPullTypes(fromServer:error:)))
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod!, swizzledMethod!)
  }
```

I matched exactly how the two methods are declared in Swift (e.g. parameter names, placeholders, etc...)

Comment: How does the new method look when it's imported into Objective C? There's probably a subtle difference.

Comment: Although exchanging implementations should work with parameters (assuming the parameter types are the same), it's actually subtly problematic.   [This article](https://newrelic.com/blog/best-practices/right-way-to-swizzle) explains why.   I have a GItHub repo for swizzling Obj-C methods from Swift called [SwizzleHelper](https://github.com/chipjarred/SwizzleHelper) that can help make it easier.  I don't have any forwarding functions for methods that take closures (Obj-C blocks) though.  I swizzle use it in another package to swizzle methods that take `NSEvent` though.

Comment: Your question prompted me add swizzling methods that take Objc-C blocks to SwizzleHelper, and I found it necessary to add `@convention(block)` in the signature for Swift-side methods that I'm swizzling.  So in your case maybe `func swizzledPullTypes(fromServer completionBlock: @escaping @convention(block) (Any) -> Void, error errorBlock: @escaping MKNKErrorBlock)`.  I don't know but I suspect that `MKNKErrorBlock` is already `@convention(block)`.  I've also realized I should add support for swizzling class methods, which you are doing.  I've only needed it for instance methods.

Comment: Thanks, @ChipJarred. So far, I can't understand how to use your package.

Comment: I haven't added swizzling class methods so it may not be directly useful to you after all.  But for swizzling instance methods, define an extension for the object type you want to swizzle a method of, define your swizzled method to do what you want to do, and to chain to the original implementation you call the appropriate `callReplacedMethod...` method specifying the original selector.   Those `callReplacedMethod...` function are in `NSObject+Swizzling.swift`.  I use its the CustomToolTip package linked in the README.   In it, `NSView+CustomToolTip.swift` is the place to look.

Comment: The `private static swizzleCustomToolTipMethods()` method is where I do the actual swizzling.  Methods like `mouseExited_CustomToolTip(with:)` show how I do the forwarding.  I plan to eventually add a HOW-TO section in the SwizzleHelper README, but haven't made time for it so far.  At the moment, it's mainly a support package for CustomToolTip, though a couple of other people have forked it. I don't know what they're using it for.  I also intend to add support for swizzling class methods.

Comment: SwizzleHelper also has unit tests where you can see how the swizzling and forwarding is done with the package.

Comment: In your example, you don't call the original implementation, so the problem with the exchange methods approach doesn't apply.  If that's the case in your real code, as opposed to just a simplified example for SO, it may just be a matter of using `@convention(block)` in what you're already doing, as in `class func swizzledPullTypes(fromServer completionBlock: @escaping @convention(block) (Any) -> Void, error errorBlock: @escaping MKNKErrorBlock)`

Comment: It occurs to me that I haven't asked an obvious question, what manner of "not working" are you seeing?  Does it compile and run, but your swizzled method isn't called?  Does it crash?

Comment: "Not working" means the Swift function `swizzledPullTypes` doesn't get called at all

Comment: Okay, I think this just works. Turned out that a function that calls this `pullTypes` missed a condition during tests. I just didn't check it fully until @ChipJarred asked about the manner of not working. I appreciate your time here, Jarred.